# Ambiguous call to class member's reference

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Say if I have a binary tree node defined like this: (and just assume all members are public for convenience...)

```
    class node
    {
    public:
       int v;
       node* left;
       node* right;
    //member functions....
    }
```

And I have two node pointers named A and B and run the following script:

```
    node* A;
    node* B;
    A->left = B;
    A->left = NULL;
```

Does that make B point to NULL or it only changes A's left child pointer (i.e. this->left in *A) and B still remains what it used to point to?

If the former case is true, how can I change A->left's value without affecting B?

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. `A->left = NULL` only changes the value of `A->left`.

Note: I'm assuming that `A` and `B` has been initialized somehow, because if you run

```
node* A; //uninitialized
node* B; //uninitialized
A->left = B;
A->left = NULL;
```

you'll get a crash.

**Update/Clarification:** Most likely, I mean. But even if it will work (for instance, due to your phenomenal (lack of) luck you might get a garbage value pointing to a valid memory region), it won't do anything good. If you'll get a valid memory region, and writing there will bring some desirable result, stop debugging immediately, and go to a nearby casino, you're having a lucky day :)

Comment: UB is not necessary a crash :/.

Comment: @Jarod42, with 99.84% probability (the value is measured and accurate :) ) in this exact case it is, so I decided not to dig into it. "This is UB" sounds like "it will probably work, but it is very likely to break somewhere for some reason". And in this case (we dereference a garbage value as a pointer and attempt to write something there) it will crash (almost) everywhere. Unless the OP is very (un)lucky or his compiler is very witty. Still, if you wish, I'll edit the answer now to make it more specific.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I forget to type the code of initializing A and B (Apologize that cause I'm more focusing on the question itself rather than the code. Just to make sure that accessing A->left is essentially accessing the address of (&A+sizeof(int)), right? (i.e. this->left instead of B))

Comment: @SUNSiqi, I understand :) that's why in the original answer I didn't pay much attention to it. But since others did, I decided to clarify a bit. Yes, you get it right. The only thing that is wrong is that it's not &A+sizeof(int), but &A+offset_of_left_inside_node_class, In general case the compiler might pack the content of the node class differently (for instance, if you have a 'char' field, it might take 4 bytes instead of 1). But the general idea is correct.